# MySQL 5.7 Triggers to perform update on another table

Tags: mysql

Please, I have two tables. The first is Loans and the second Loan_Balance. I wish to update the column "Status" in the Loans table based on the value in "Balance" column of  Loan_Balance table. I created a trigger for this and it did not work. Below is my code. Please help me.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_afterupdate` 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON `Loan_Balance`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT Balance FROM Loan_Balance WHERE LoanID = Old.LoanID ) = 0
    THEN 
        UPDATE Loans 
        SET Status = 'COMPLETED'
        WHERE LoanID = Old.LoanID;
    END IF; 
END
```

Comment: please don't say "did not work". tell us what you tried and what _did_ happen.

Comment: note that mysql 5.7 is no longer supported and not receiving security updates; consider it insecure and upgrade as soon as possible

Comment: Please this is the error message i received.     #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

Comment: You don't appear to be setting delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the trigger in the command line client, or some other clients, they will look for `;` as the end of a statement.  When you need a `;` in your trigger, you need to change the delimiter the client uses, e.g.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_afterupdate` 
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON `Loan_Balance`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF ( SELECT Balance FROM Loan_Balance WHERE LoanID = Old.LoanID ) = 0
    THEN 
        UPDATE Loans 
        SET Status = 'COMPLETED'
        WHERE LoanID = Old.LoanID;
    END IF; 
END
$$
delimiter ;
```

But you have an additional problem: you are marking a loan as COMPLETED when the Loan_Balance is updated and the *previous* balance was 0.  If the update changes the balance, that will leave COMPLETED loans with a non-0 balance.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qY9d3s2R)